# GUI Toolkit with Good Designer for Python

Tags: python, user-interface, toolkit

I am looking for a GUI toolkit which also has a good designer (like visual studio) for Python language.

It should have
...Good Documentation
...Good IDE + Designer
...Cross Platform Support (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) (LGPL binding for QT) with QT Designer

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) for a GUI toolkit with [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) as the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about dnd like Visual Studio but [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) is very good toolkit

EDIT: [QT Designer](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Creating_GUI_Applications_with_PyQt_and_Qt_Designer) seems good too.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PyQt together with Qt Designer, nice documentation and cross platform support.